# build multiple projects using maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, maven-3

I have 7 projects in my local environment and some of them depend on each other. I have built them in a particular sequence to prepare my development environment. I have to do update dependency and then maven clean install on each project in a particular sequence for this.
Is there any shortcut to do this instead of the manual steps? How do I create a run configuration ( or any other way) to build all projects in some sequence?

-Sunil

Answer (score 3):

If these 7 projects are parts of a whole project then what you need is a [Maven multi-module project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).  When you are done setting it up the directory structure will look like:

```
project-root
   |
   +-- project-1
   |
   +-- project-2
   .
   .
   |
   +-- project-7
```

On the other hand if these are just 7 otherwise independent project you would set up dependencies in each project on other related projects.

Be aware that in the latter case of independent projects, just because you build `project-x` it doesn't mean that `project-y` will pick up changes.  When you build `project-x` you have to do `mvn install` to ensure that it gets pushed to your local Maven repository.  Then you have to run `mvn package` (or `mvn install`) on `project-y`.

Since you are using Eclipse I would highly recommend installing the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).  It will greatly simplify keeping your Eclipse configuration in lock-step with any POM changes.