# How to import a maven project and make it a module of another project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

New to Java and I'm probably not understanding something correctly. I have an existing maven project in GIT that I'm trying to pull down and make a module of another project I already have set up in Spring Tool Suite.

When I do a file import I don't see an option to specify the parent pom.xml. How do I do it? Thanks for any helpful tips

Comment: What does STS stand for?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite

Comment: When you say "make a module of another project", you mean you wish to permanently combine the two projects into a multi-module project? As opposed to just declaring a dependency on the existing project

Comment: This might be where I'm not getting it. The project I'm pulling in is basically a soap stub for calling web services. The other project I already have up and running will be calling it to get data.

Comment: Possible a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495287/build-multiple-projects-using-maven-in-eclipse

Comment: @Vargan - thank you, this looks a lot easier. Instead of creating a multi-module project I'll simply set it up as a dependency.

Comment: @fumeng I'm confused. The link he posted **does** show a multi-module project. It sounds like that is not what you want.

Comment: ...as 1 option. The other is to simply add a dependency -- which seems a bit easier to accomplish my goal.

Comment: @fumeng It is not a matter of "easier". It's a matter of what is conceptually correct. Both are easy. It sounds like you should be declaring a dependency, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you probably don't want to go that road but instead setup the projects as dependencies when needed. This is how I did setup project in eclipse when I was using it. I am now using IntelliJ, which does solve a variety of issues I had with eclipse and I would recommend checking it up.

Here's an excellent answer on how to setup the projects: [build multiple projects using maven in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495287/build-multiple-projects-using-maven-in-eclipse)